# Dynamically create list items from local xml file

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest, appcelerator, createelement

I'm trying to create a menu from an XML file. The HTML file that I want to create the menu in, is located my main project folder. This folder also contains an xml folder in which my xml file (fruitDB.xml) is located. I understood that there are several ways of loading XML files and that some ways only work online. Eventually the menu is used for an HTML5 mobile app (don't know if this is usefull information), build using Appcelerator.

I've read some sources but it's still not clear to me how I can load an XML file. I have the following code in my header tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function init(){
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "xml/fruitDB.xml", false);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        xmlhttp.send();
        var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
        var Fruits = xmlDoc[];

        alert(Fruits);

        for (var i = 0; i < Fruits.children.length; i++) {
            alert("hi");
            var Fruit = Fruits.children[i];
            var Name = Fruits.getElementsByTagName("name");
            var Thumb = Fruits.getElementsByTagName("image");

            var list = document.getElementById("menuButtons");
            var listEntry = document.createElement("LI");
            listEntry.document.createTextNode(Name);
            list.appendChild(listEntry);
        }
    }

</script>
```

What I try to do here is open the init(); function using , load the xml file, though I'm not sure if giving a path (like I'm doing) is correct. After the XML is loaded it should create new

's in my HTML file and give them name (and eventually an image) which are stored in the xml file until all items from the xml are placed as list items. Sorry for the long sentence :P.

At xmlhttp.send(); I recieved the following error in my console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/folder/folder/folder/xml/fruitDB.xml. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Does this mean that using XMLHttpRequest won't work on local files and if not what other way can I use in order to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

XML doesn't have great support in Titanium. Also XML is often a pain to work with..

Why not use a JSON payload / document instead!

Format the JSON so it is an array of fruit objects

Then you just parse the payload into a javascript object that comes back from the web-service or your local file something like this:

```
var fruits = JSON.parse(yourHTTPObj.responseData);
```

Now you can loop over the fruit objects and say:

```
if (fruits[i].type === 'Apple') { //do something };
```